# MediaRecorder.ondataavailable data returns 0

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, mediarecorder

I am recording an image stream on an offscreen canvas, then trying to download the recorded data. Whenever I download the resulting video it is zero bytes.

When I call `mediaRecorder.stop()`, the `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable` does fire, but the data property is empty — it logs as `Blob(0) {size: 0, type: "video/webm"}`.

I read [littlebird's answer to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677776/mediarecorder-ondataavailable-data-size-is-always-0), where he suggests that Chrome's Experimental Web Platform Features needs to be enabled. After enabling this in chrome://flags, I'm still running into the problem.

My code is pasted below. This worked back in March 2017 when I initially wrote it, but now that I'm trying to run it again I'm having the error. I thought something must have changed in Chrome, but I haven't been able to track anything down.

```
this._createMediaRecorder = function(frame) {
  var newMediaRecorder;

  // Create hidden canvas to draw to
  newHiddenCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  newHiddenCanvas.setAttribute('id', frame + Date.now());

  newHiddenCanvas.width = DEPTHWIDTH;
  newHiddenCanvas.height = DEPTHHEIGHT;

  newHiddenContext = hiddenCanvas.getContext("2d");
  newHiddenContext.fillRect(0, 0, newHiddenCanvas.width, newHiddenCanvas.height);

  // Add canvas to hidden div
  myDiv.appendChild(newHiddenCanvas);

  // Create media recorder, add canvas to recorder
  newMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(newHiddenCanvas.captureStream());
  newMediaRecorder.canvas = newHiddenCanvas;

  var mediaChunks = [];

  newMediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {

      // The video as a blob
      var blobVideo = new Blob(mediaChunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm' });

      // Download the video 
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blobVideo);
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.style = 'display: none';
      a.href = url;
      a.download = frame + Date.now() + '.webm';
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      // Reset media chunks
      mediaChunks.length = 0;    

  }.bind(this);

  // When video data is available
  newMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    mediaChunks.push(e.data); // This returns Blob(0) {size: 0, type: "video/webm"}
  };

  // Start recording
  newMediaRecorder.start();
  return newMediaRecorder;
};
```

Comment: And you do draw on your canvas after the MediaStream has been initialised?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks. Your comment put me on the right track. The issue was that the image that I was drawing to the canvas needed to load before I could draw to the hidden canvas. I moved drawing to the hidden canvas into the img.onload function and it is now working.

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same issue (MediaRecorder.ondataavailable Blob(0) {size: 0, type: "video/webm"}) on mac chrome browser.

However, the same code works perfectly fine on windows chrome.

Tried enabling Chrome's experimental Web Platform Features on chrome, but no luck.
Unable to identify why the same code does not run on mac OS using chrome.

```js
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;
let sourceBuffer;
const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');
const recordedVideo = document.querySelector('video#recorded');
const recordButton = document.querySelector('button#record');
recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (recordButton.textContent === 'Start Recording') {
        startRecording();
    } else {
        stopRecording();
        recordButton.textContent = 'Start Recording';
        downloadButton.disabled = false;
    }
});
const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { type: 'video/mp4; "codecs=vp9,opus"' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'recordedvideo.mp4';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 100);
});
function handleSourceOpen() {
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus');
}
function handleDataAvailable(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
    }
}
function startRecording() {
    recordedBlobs = [];
    let options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus',
        bitsPerSecond: 1421000
    };
    if (window.stream) {
        if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
            console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
            errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
            options = { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus' };
            if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
                console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
                errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
                options = { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus' };
                if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
                    console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
                    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
                    options = { mimeType: '' };
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
        let constraints = {
            frameRate: 25,
            width: 1280,
            height: 720
        };
        mediaRecorder.stream.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints(constraints);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
        errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`;
        return;
    }
    recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
    downloadButton.disabled = true;
    mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
    };
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    mediaRecorder.start(); 
}
function stopRecording() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
}
function handleSuccess(stream) {
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    window.stream = stream;
}
async function init() {
    try {
        var vi = document.querySelector('iframe[#xyz_iframe]').contentDocument.body.querySelector('video[autoplay]');
        var stream;
        stream = vi.captureStream();
        handleSuccess(stream);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('navigator.getUserMedia error:', e);
        errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia error:${e.toString()}`;
    }
}
document.querySelector('button#start').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    await init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when the video caller in from os x safari on. Works fine when the video caller is from firefox.

But if the caller if from os x safari, and I am recording on firefox, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the codec I was using, VP8 was fine until chrome 106 but it breaks in chrome 107, changing it to vp9 fixed it.

Now I removed the coded definition and letting the browser decide what to use `video/webm; codecs=opus`