# mediaRecorder.ondataavailable is not working in angular 4

Tags: angular, webrtc

I am trying to send the live streaming data to nodeJS server from angular 4 so I am using socket.io and webRtc for streaming.

```
constructor(private _chatService: ChatService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.video = document.querySelector('video');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints).then(
      stream => {
        this.video.srcObject = stream;
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        console.log(mediaRecorder);  // it produces result 
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
          console.log('Data', e.data); // but it is not working
        };

      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      });
  }
```

My code seems fine to me but I don't know why  `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable` is not working.
I am using `console.log()` inside `ondataavailable` method but that `console` never runs.

Comment: check whether this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677776/mediarecorder-ondataavailable-data-size-is-always-0

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya, no, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
mediaRecorder.start(3000)
```